# How to derive the discrete fourier transform of $(n+2)a^nu[n]$ where $|a| < 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

This is a rather simple question, but I'm stuck on one step. Here's what I've done:

1) $x[n] = (n+2)(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n] = n(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n]+2(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n]$

The discrete fourier transform is defined as $X(e^{-i\omega}) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n]e^{-i\omega n}$

2) Therefore, $X(e^{-i\omega}) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (n(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n]+2(\frac{1}{2})^nu[n])e^{-i\omega n} = \sum\limits_{n= 0}^{\infty} (n(\frac{1}{2})^n+2(\frac{1}{2})^n)e^{-i\omega n}$

The second term in the sum is a geometric series that converges to $\frac{2}{1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\omega}}$.

However, I'm stuck on the first term. What does $\sum\limits_{n= 0}^{\infty} n(\frac{1}{2})^ne^{-i\omega n}$ converge to?

I have a solution that says it converges to $\frac{\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\omega}}{(1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\omega})^2}$.

If the solution is correct, how does one arrive at it? In other words, what type of series is it and what is the proof of its convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n ~ a^n$ you can treat this with some trickery as: $$a \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n ~ a^n = a ~ \frac{d}{da} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n =  a ~ \frac{d}{da} \frac {1}{1-a} = \frac a {(1 - a)^2}.$$ Repeat as necessary for any polynomial you wish.

Comment: Well, that is certainly some trickery, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: If it helps to see why it works, take a piece of graph paper and label the x-axis with $1, a, a^2, a^3, ...$ and draw the graph of $n$ as the points $(1,1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), ...$. Imagine summing all of the dots and you get a sum of $n a^n$. Now do the first horizontal sum, which is a sum of $a a^n$. Add this to the second horizontal sum, which is a sum of $a^2 a^n$ since it's shifted right by one. The next one is $a^3 a^n$. So you get $(a + a^2 + a^3 + \dots)(1 + a + a^2 + \dots)$.